# Grepping for a pattern followed by another pattern and excluding what lies inbetween as ouput

Tags: regex, grep

I want to do something like

```
egrep -o '(mon|tues)[1-3]?[0-9].*(mon|tues)[1-3]?[0-9]'
```

And only get what isn't found by the (mon|tues)[1-3]?[0-9]

With this as input

```
mon19hellotues20
mon19world
hellomon19
tues8worldtues22
```

I want

```
mon19tues20
tues8tues22
```

As output

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is better tool for this to print certain matched txt in output:

```
sed -nE 's/(mon|tues)([1-3]{0,1}[0-9]).*(mon|tues)([1-3]{0,1}[0-9])/\1\2\3\4/p' file

mon19tues20
tues8tues22
```